# Count of boolean values of an array in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

this.employee = [
            {
                name: "A",
                isexperienced: true;
                },
            {
              name: "B",
                isexperienced: true;
                },
                 {
              name: "C",
                isexperienced: false;
                },

//here i need the count of true values

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const experienced = this.employee.reduce((acc, e) => e.isexperienced ? acc+1 : acc, 0);
```

Secondly, your employee array is not correct:

- There should be no `;` after `true`, `false`
- There is no closing `]`